# javascript alert() is not showing correct run time of a web application

Tags: javascript, datatables, sheetjs

Using the following code, I am trying to display an uploaded excel file in the browser in [datatable](https://datatables.net/) format. For large files with more than 1000 rows and 25 columns, it takes ~3-4 secs which I believe can be improved. However, this time is measured using a stopwatch on a mobile phone. To measure the accurate time I used performance.now() inside the code, however, the alert function is not displaying the time correctly. how to fix this? and also is it possible to reduce the file loading time? thanks.

```
<html>

<head>
    <!-- libs needed for datatable -->
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> -->
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <!-- libs need for sheetJS -->
    <script lang="javascript" src="sheetjs-master/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom js script with util functions -->
    <script src="js_uitlities.js"></script>

    <!-- AdminLTE -->
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLTE-3.0.5/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLTE-3.0.5/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- browse excel -->
    <!-- <div id="wrapper"> -->
    <div class="custom-file mb-2 mt-2">
        <!-- <input type="file" id="input-excel"> -->
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="input-excel">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
        <script>
            // Add the following code if you want the name of the file appear on select
            $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function () {
                var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
            });
        </script>
    </div>

    <!-- display table in datatable format -->
    <div id="my_tab">
        <h3 id="tab_title"></h3>
        <p id="timer"></p>
        <table id="my_datatable" class="display"></table>
        <tr>
    </div>

    <!-- dynamically create table using uploaded xlsx -->
    <script>
        load_excel('#input-excel');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and content of js_uitlities.js is as follows:

```
// load excel file using jquery and time it
function load_excel(excel_id) {
    // const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');
    if (typeof require !== 'undefined') performance = require('perf_hooks');
    const t0 = performance.now();
    $(excel_id).change(function (e) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      // var timerStart = Date.now();
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
  
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
        var wb = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: 'array'
        });
  
        var htmlstr = XLSX.write(wb, {
          sheet: "",
          type: 'binary',
          bookType: 'html'
        });
        htmlstr = modify_htmlstr(htmlstr, "<tr>", "</tr>", "<thead>", "</thead>");
  
        document.getElementById("my_tab").firstElementChild.innerHTML = 'Uploaded excel file';
        document.getElementById("my_datatable").innerHTML = htmlstr;
        $("#my_datatable").DataTable();
        const t1 = performance.now();
        var time_dfiff = t1 - t0;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML  = "time taken = " + time_dfiff + " secs";
        console.log(time_dfiff);
        alert("time taken = " + time_dfiff + " secs");
        // alert("time to load the table is "+ Date.now() - timerStart);
      }
    });
  }

// modify htmlstr as returned by XLSX.write function
function modify_htmlstr(htmlstr, pat, pat2, str_after_open_match, str_after_close_match) {
    var open_match = htmlstr.search(pat);
    var close_match = htmlstr.search(pat2);
    htmlstr_sub = htmlstr.substring(open_match, close_match)
    htmlstr_sub_rep = htmlstr_sub.replace(/td/gi, "th")
    htmlstr = [htmlstr.slice(0, open_match), htmlstr_sub_rep, htmlstr.slice(close_match)].join('');
    htmlstr = [htmlstr.slice(0, open_match), str_after_open_match, htmlstr.slice(open_match)].join('');
    close_match = htmlstr.search(pat2) + pat2.length;
    htmlstr = [htmlstr.slice(0, close_match), str_after_close_match, htmlstr.slice(close_match)].join('');
    return (htmlstr);
  }


function modify_htmlstr_mannual(htmlstr) {
    var output = "<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'/><title>SheetJS Table Export</title></head><body><table><thead><tr><th>uniprot</th><th>logFC</th></thead></tr><tr><td>P49327</td><td>1.059124008</td></tr><tr><td>P40121</td><td>2.676020531</td></tr></table></body></html>"
    return(output);
}
```

Comment: I have good experiences with [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)

Comment: @Gerard, thanks for your time. using console.time I see it takes ~2900ms, what optimizations should I make it to reduce further?